# Word 2010 / CustomXMLParts / Content Controls

Tags: xml, ms-word

I have a Microsoft Word 2010 Document which I have a few content controls for user interaction. I would like to populate and DropdownListEntries from a CustomXMLPart XML Document. I have added a CustomXMLPart and loaded my XML document to the CustomXMLPart but am unsure how to ??Bind?? the Content Control to the CustomXMLPart. Below is my Code and XML Document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<SitesTable>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="BXR">COMPHIBRON ONE</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="AOT5205">MT EVERGREEN STATE</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="AK4543">MV LTC JOHN U D PAGE</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="AK4544">MV SSG EDWARD A CARTER JR</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="AK323">MV TSGT JOHN A CHAPMAN</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="AK5065">SS CAPE MOHICAN</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="AVB4">SS CURTISS</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="AK 3015">USNS 1ST HARRY L MARTIN</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="AK 3010">USNS 1ST LT BALDOMERO LOPEZ</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="AK 3008">USNS 2ND LT JOHN P BOBO</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="AGOS 20">USNS ABLE</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="CVN 73">USS GEORGE WASHINGTON</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="SSGN 729">USS GEORGIA</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="CVN 78">USS GERALD R FORD</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="LSD 42">USS GERMANTOWN</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="CG 64">USS GETTYSBURG</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="MCM 11">USS GLADIATOR</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="DDG 66">USS GONZALEZ</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="DDG 107">USS GRAVELY</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="LPD 20">USS GREEN BAY</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="SSN 772">USS GREENEVILLE</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="DDG 101">USS GRIDLEY</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="LSD 44">USS GUNSTON HALL</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="DDG 97">USS HALSEY</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="SSN 767">USS HAMPTON</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="LSD 49">USS HARPERS FERRY</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="CVN 75">USS HARRY S TRUMAN</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="SSN 768">USS HARTFORD</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="SSN 776">USS HAWAII</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="SSN 725">USS HELENA</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="SSBN 730">USS HENRY M JACKSON</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="DDG 76">USS HIGGINS</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="DDG 70">USS HOPPER</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="SSN 713">USS HOUSTON</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="DDG 83">USS HOWARD</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="CG 66">USS HUE CITY</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="PC 3">USS HURRICANE</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="SSN 786">USS ILLINOIS</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="LCS 2">USS INDEPENDENCE</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="SSN 789">USS INDIANA</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="LHD 7">USS IWO JIMA</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="LCS 6">USS JACKSON</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="SSN 699">USS JACKSONVILLE</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="DDG 95">USS JAMES E WILLIAMS</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="DDG 109">USS JASON DUNHAM</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="SSN 759">USS JEFFERSON CITY</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="SSN 23">USS JIMMY CARTER</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="CVN 74">USS JOHN C STENNIS</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="DDG 53">USS JOHN PAUL JONES</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="DDG 56">USS JOHN S MCCAIN</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="SSN 785">USS JOHN WARNER</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="LHD 3">USS KEARSARGE</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="SSBN 737">USS KENTUCKY</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="DDG 100">USS KIDD</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="SSN 701">USS LA JOLLA</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="DDG 58">USS LABOON</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="CG 57">USS LAKE CHAMPLAIN</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="CG 70">USS LAKE ERIE</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="DDG 82">USS LASSEN</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="CG 55">USS LEYTE GULF</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="SSBN 743">USS LOUISIANA</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="CG 59">USS PRINCETON</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="SSN 719">USS PROVIDENCE</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="DDG 61">USS RAMAGE</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="SSBN 740">USS RHODE ISLAND</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="CVN 76">USS RONALD REAGAN</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="DDG 80">USS ROOSEVELT</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="DDG 71">USS ROSS</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="LSD 47">USS RUSHMORE</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="DDG 59">USS RUSSELL</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="DDG 102">USS SAMPSON</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="LPD 17">USS SAN ANTONIO</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="LPD 22">USS SAN DIEGO</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="SSN 711">USS SAN FRANCISCO</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="CG 56">USS SAN JACINTO</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="SSN 751">USS SAN JUAN</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="SSN 763">USS SANTA FE</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="MCM 8">USS SCOUT</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="SSN 756">USS SCRANTON</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="SSN 21">USS SEAWOLF</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="MCM 3">USS SENTRY</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="CG 67">USS SHILOH</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="DDG 86">USS SHOUP</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="LPD 25">USS SOMERSET</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="SSN 790">USS SOUTH DAKOTA</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="SSN 761">USS SPRINGFIELD</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="DDG 111">USS SPRUANCE</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="DDG 104">USS STERETT</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="DDG 63">USS STETHEM</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="DDG 106">USS STOCKDALE</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="DDG 55">USS STOUT</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="SSBN 734">USS TENNESSEE</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="SSN 775">USS TEXAS</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="SSBN 736">USS WEST VIRGINIA</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="LSD 41">USS WHIDBEY ISLAND</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="DDG 110">USS WILLIAM P LAWRENCE</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="DDG 81">USS WINSTON S CHURCHILL</site>
    </SiteRow>
    <SiteRow>
        <site hull="SSBN 742">USS WYOMING</site>
    </SiteRow>
</SitesTable>
```

Below is the Code written into ThisDocument:

```
Sub ReadCustomXML()
On Error GoTo ErrorReadCustomXMLInfo

'Declares variables
Dim XMLNameSpace        As String
Dim XMLNameSpaceCustom  As String
Dim XMLNameSpacePrefix  As String

Dim XMLParts            As CustomXMLParts
Dim XMLPart             As CustomXMLPart

Dim XMLSiteNodes        As CustomXMLNodes
Dim XMLSiteNode         As CustomXMLNode
Dim XMLHullNodes        As CustomXMLNodes
Dim XMLHullNode         As CustomXMLNode

Dim i                   As Integer
Dim strXPath            As String
Dim ListItemEntry       As String
Dim objXMLMapping       As XMLMapping


'Set the Documents-Level CustomXMLParts
Set XMLParts = ThisDocument.CustomXMLParts
Debug.Print XMLParts.Count

If XMLParts.Count > 4 Then
    For Each XMLPart In XMLParts
        'Deletes the CustomXMLPart
        CustomXMLParts.SelectByNamespace("").item(1).Delete
    Next XMLPart
    'Adds a CustomXMLPart to the Document
    CustomXMLParts.Add
    'Loads the CustomXMLPart with data from a XML File
    CustomXMLParts(CustomXMLParts.Count).Load ("C:\Users\troy.pilewski\Desktop\CSI\SiteList.xml")
    For Each XMLPart In XMLParts
        XMLNameSpace = XMLPart.NamespaceURI
        If Len(XMLNameSpace) = 0 Then
            Set XMLSiteNodes = XMLPart.SelectNodes("/SitesTable/SiteRow/site")
            If XMLSiteNodes.Count > 0 Then
                For Each XMLSiteNode In XMLSiteNodes
'                    Debug.Print XMLSiteNode.Text & " (" & XMLSiteNode.Attributes.item(1).Text & ")"
                    ListItemEntry = XMLSiteNode.Text & " (" & XMLSiteNode.Attributes.item(1).Text & ")"
                    Debug.Print ListItemEntry
                    With ActiveDocument.ContentControls(1).DropdownListEntries
                        .Add ListItemEntry
                    End With
                Next XMLSiteNode
            End If
        End If
    Next XMLPart
ElseIf XMLParts.Count = 4 Then
    For Each XMLPart In XMLParts
        'Deletes the CustomXMLPart
        CustomXMLParts.SelectByNamespace("").item(1).Delete
    Next XMLPart
    'Adds a CustomXMLPart to the Document
    CustomXMLParts.Add
    'Loads the CustomXMLPart with data from a XML File
    CustomXMLParts(CustomXMLParts.Count).Load ("C:\Users\troy.pilewski\Desktop\CSI\SiteList.xml")
    For Each XMLPart In XMLParts
        XMLNameSpace = XMLPart.NamespaceURI
        If Len(XMLNameSpace) = 0 Then
            Set XMLSiteNodes = XMLPart.SelectNodes("/SitesTable/SiteRow/site")
            If XMLSiteNodes.Count > 0 Then
                For Each XMLSiteNode In XMLSiteNodes
'                    Debug.Print XMLSiteNode.Text & " (" & XMLSiteNode.Attributes.item(1).Text & ")"
                    ListItemEntry = XMLSiteNode.Text & " (" & XMLSiteNode.Attributes.item(1).Text & ")"
                    Debug.Print ListItemEntry
                    With ActiveDocument.ContentControls(1).DropdownListEntries
                        .Add ListItemEntry
                    End With
                Next XMLSiteNode
            End If
        End If
    Next XMLPart
Else
    'Adds a CustomXMLPart to the Document
    CustomXMLParts.Add
    'Loads the CustomXMLPart with data from a XML File
    CustomXMLParts(CustomXMLParts.Count).Load ("C:\Users\troy.pilewski\Desktop\CSI\SiteList.xml")
    For Each XMLPart In XMLParts
        XMLNameSpace = XMLPart.NamespaceURI
        If Len(XMLNameSpace) = 0 Then
            Set XMLSiteNodes = XMLPart.SelectNodes("/SitesTable/SiteRow/site")
                For Each XMLSiteNode In XMLSiteNodes
'                    Debug.Print XMLSiteNode.Text & " (" & XMLSiteNode.Attributes.item(1).Text & ")"
                    ListItemEntry = XMLSiteNode.Text & " (" & XMLSiteNode.Attributes.item(1).Text & ")"
                    Debug.Print ListItemEntry
                    With ActiveDocument.ContentControls(1).DropdownListEntries
                        .Add ListItemEntry
                    End With
                Next XMLSiteNode
        End If
    Next XMLPart
End If


ErrorReadCustomXMLInfo:

End Sub
```

Below is the Schema:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="SitesTable">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="SiteRow" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="site">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:simpleContent>
                                        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                            <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="hull" use="optional"/>
                                        </xs:extension>
                                    </xs:simpleContent>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: It requires attaching an XML schema to the document that's also used by the Custom XML Part. Have you see this walkthrough? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398244.aspx

Comment: @CindyMeister: I have seen the referenced walkthrough. Although, it references using Visual Studio; which is not provide on the Government Asset I am working on. Would like to know how to do this via just VBA.

Comment: Setting it up (the part before any code is shown) is exactly the same. If you've already added a custom xml part, no need to worry about that section. The logic to *bind* the controls to the Custom XML Part is exactly the same with the use of XPath and XMLMapping. You have to decide how you want to refer to a particular content control, it looks like you feel comfortable with Document.ContentControls(index), so you can use that. The rest of the walk-through is not relevant for you.

Comment: @CindyMeister: I have added the XPath and XML Mapping as the Walkthrough instructed but it does not seem to work. '                XPath = "ns:SitesTable/ns:SiteRow/ns:site"
                ActiveDocument.ContentControls(1).XMLMapping.SetMapping XPath'

Comment: I can try to take a look at it tomorrow, but you could you please also add the schema. No way to test without also having your schema.

Comment: @ CindyMeister: I can email you all if you want... I can respond to your email if you want... troy.pilewski@gmail.com

Comment: No, I don't want email or documents. According to Stack Overflow guidelines, everything required to repro a problem should be made available in your Question. If the thing is large, trim it down to a simple example.

Comment: @CindyMeister: I have added the schema as requested.

Comment: Could you please indent it properly? And again, it's the end of my day, so I'll have to see if I can find time tomorrow...

Comment: I don't see how your schema provides the list of values that should appear in the dropdown? I think perhaps you misunderstand how a content control can be bound to show a list, automatically. It's done with the schema, not the custom xml part.

Comment: How would the schema have to change? I auto-generated the schema from the XML file.

Comment: Compare it to the walkhrough.

Comment: Roger! I'll look at it tonight. And try it again.